# Nested Jar with java Applet

Tags: java, applet, apache-tika

First of all, I have gone through all the questions here regarding the inclusion of jar files for an applet. But even then, I have this 'Huge' Problem.

I am developing an application with java and the Apache-Tika Library (with 4 jars, totaling the size of 40 mbs). The application needs to count the number of words in an uploaded document (doc, docx, odf, pdf and a bunch of other). The applet runs pretty well from Netbeans 6.5 or Eclipse IDE which I am using side by side for the development. But when I try to Deploy it to a browser, there's a problem.

**Problem**

The initial page loads pretty good. But as I give the path of the document and Click Ok (or Count), I get loads of error messages.
Those are all "**Class Not Found Exceptions**" related to the external Apache-Tika Library. I think I have done all the inclusion of the library correctly as other wise it wouldn't run in the applet viewer.

As for the HTML, I have created a jar of the entire Word-Counter Application, along with the library(4 Apache-Tika Jars) and all other necessary files, and included the jar in the  tag accordingly.
Do I need to mention anything on the HTML file about the nested jar library, is there a limitation regarding a nested jar? 
Any Kind of help would be Highly Appreciated.
Thank You learned Folks in advance.

Comment: *"nested jar library"* If by that you mean 'Jar inside Jar', it won't work.  The JRE is not designed to deal with archives inside other archives - it would require a custom class loader (which is possible in a trusted applet).

Comment: Can your user's be expected to be running a Plug-In 2 (e.g. Oracle's 1.6.0_10+) JRE?  It would allow lazy downloads of the Jars, and sand-boxed access to the local file-system.

Comment: The applet needs external library, which are all jars. SO, by this it means Applet doesn't support external jar library? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **"Class Not Found Exceptions"** related to the external Apache-Tika Library.

Multiple Jars can be listed in the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.  See [W3C on the archive attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.4)..

> This attribute specifies a *comma-separated* list of URIs for archives containing classes and other resources that will be "preloaded".

Comment: It worked and it didn't. The **Class Not Found Exception** is gone, but now the applet isn't responding at all. Now If I may ask, What's the best way to debug?

Comment: It seems time for a new question "(How to) Debug frozen applet(?)".

Comment: Problem Solved. THe applet access to local file, so I needed to Sign it, which i did and voila! It worked. The applet is up and running and @Andrew Thompson and pra9ma - "I Thank You Both".

Comment: 1) pra9ma will not be notified of your comment unless it is made in reply to their answer. 2) A good way to show thanks is to up-vote the post(s) you found helpful (on this or any other thread). 3) Glad you got the applet problems sorted.  :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you may be approaching this the wrong way. You really shouldn't be doing any document analysis from a browser Applet. Instead upload the document to a server and analyze it there. Requiring users to download 40MBs of jars is probably unacceptable as an end solution to anyone who will use the application you are creating.

Comment: Well, the size of the library can be downsized to around less than 2 MB. I can repack the library with only the classes that I need. So That wont be a problem. The problem is exactly what I stated. I want to test my applet locally and then I will take care of the size. I need to make the applet work with a browser (and not just the applet viewer).

Comment: Perhaps you should edit the title of the question to better reflect your inquiry.  "Applet using nested Jar" seems a more relevant title.

Comment: Anish, I'm sure the jars can be repackaged and compacted, etc. The question I really have, is why you'd want to do any kind of document analysis front the client-side? I've definitely had a case where I've needed to use an Applet for some client-side hardware interfacing, but that was a very special case. For what you are describing, it sounds like you could avoid the whole Applet problem entirely and do it all on the server. Maybe I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: @pra9ma : I need the service/application to be online. So, the users can upload their documents and get the count of the words in their document instantaneously (after the upload completes, that is) . And I also need the process to be **automated**.  I'd be grateful if there's another (better) direction then this.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : I'm a newbie. Thank You and I will just do that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just include all the classes from all the dependency jars inside your applet jar?

Tika includes a single jar that does that very thing - `tika-app.jar`. You can run the `tika-app` without needing any extra jars or dependencies, it includes everything that's required.

If you look at the tika-app pom, you'll see the appropriate maven magic to have such a jar built. Otherwise, to do it by hand, simply unpack all your jars into a single directory, then re-jar that up again.

Comment: Poor strategy.  Often violates the license of the libraries, and makes JWS lazy download impossible and auto-update painful.